# cobbler reposync referencing old repo data

Tags: repository, cobbler

This one has me scratching my head:

I added a repo to my cobblerd box, which was otherwise a happy CentOS7 cobbler server for a few small repos:

```
cobbler repo add --name spacewalk-client25-6-x86_64 --mirror http://yum.spacewalkproject.org/2.5-client/RHEL/7/x86_64
cobbler reposync --only spacewalk-client25-6-x86_64
```

Then I noticed I had the URL wrong.  Doh!  6 is not like 7.

```
cobbler repo edit --name spacewalk-client25-6-x86_64  --mirror http://yum.spacewalkproject.org/2.5-client/RHEL/6/x86_64
```

On the resync, though, first odd things happened:  It didn't download anything new, and kept the EL7 stuff.  So I whacked the tree: (nukeItFromOrbit.gifv)

```
rm -rf /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/spacewalk-client25-6-x86_64
cobbler reposync --only spacewalk-client25-6-x86_64
```

And then bad things happened:  it was complaining about not finding some EL7 stuff, even though it shouldn't even be looking!

```
:
:
rhn-virtualization-common-5.4. FAILED
:
rhnpush-5.5.98-1.el7.noarch.rp FAILED
:
spacewalk-backend-libs-2.5.43-1.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
spacewalk-client-cert-2.5.3-1.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
:
:
```

Very weird -- you see where it's still looking for EL7 stuff?  So I cursed, shook my fist, and cobbler synced in the hopes of clearing any lingering cache-like nuisance.  But that didn't fix it hard enough, so I removed the repo, and synced THAT, and then re-added it and reposynched.  No dice.  Restarted cobblerd.  Nope.  Killed the repo, restarted cobblerd, synched it twice, re-added the repo.  Nope.  And yes, the URL was the right one.  ;-)

So I got crafty:  define a new repo ('86_64 2') , synch ITS data, and slide that over into the name (which can't be changed easily for config-management and $releasevar reasons):

```
cobbler repo add --name spacewalk-client25-6-x86_642 --mirror http://yum.spacewalkproject.org/2.5-client/RHEL/6/x86_64
cobbler reposync --only spacewalk-client25-6-x86_642
cobbler repo rename --name spacewalk-client25-6-x86_642 --newname spacewalk-client25-6-x86_64
cobbler reposync --only spacewalk-client25-6-x86_64

:
:
Removing obsolete spacewalk-client-cert-2.5.3-1.el6.noarch.rpm
Removing obsolete rhn-setup-gnome-2.5.16-1.el6.noarch.rpm
Removing obsolete yum-rhn-plugin-2.5.5-1.el6.noarch.rpm
Removing obsolete spacewalk-oscap-2.5.3-1.el6.noarch.rpm
:
:
spacewalk-client-repo-2.5-3.el FAILED
spacewalk-koan-2.5.2-1.el7.noa FAILED
spacewalk-oscap-2.5.3-1.el7.no FAILED
yum-rhn-plugin-2.5.5-1.el7.noa FAILED
rhnpush-5.5.98-1.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
rhn-virtualization-common-5.4.55-1.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
:
:
```

Yeah, really.

Something's up, but `strace -e trace=file` didn't pop anything out either.  Anyone seen this?  Do you want to see a full reposynch run on that repo, for kicks?

(feel free to adjust the 'repository' tag to be 'reposync' so it's more accurate.  I can't do it on my lame rep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As luck has it, I fell over the answer almost right after posting.

`/var/cache/yum` has a redundant cache of usually-tasty repo data, but it even keeps the sour ones deleted long ago: I found a `spacewalk-client25-6-x86_642` in there from the crafty attempt above, as well as the old `spacewalk-client25-6-x86_64` one that it then refused to update.

I whacked that, chuckling malevolently, and resynched.

```
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
cobbler reposync --only spacewalk-client25-6-x86_64
```

And life was good.